# How can i find out if a battery is internal/external from command line in Linux?

Tags: linux, types, battery

Is there any way to find out if a battery is internal or external from command line in Linux ?

I tried :

```
upower -i `upower -e | grep 'BAT'`
```

But i dont find the battery type:

```
native-path:          BAT1
vendor:               LG
model:                Li_Ion_4000mA
serial:               00D6
power supply:         yes
updated:              Tue 12 Apr 2016 01:03:41 PM EEST (52 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes
battery
present:             yes
rechargeable:        yes
state:               fully-charged
warning-level:       none
energy:              39.5388 Wh
energy-empty:        0 Wh
energy-full:         39.5388 Wh
energy-full-design:  47.52 Wh
energy-rate:         0.0108 W
voltage:             12.369 V
percentage:          100%
capacity:            83.2045%
technology:          lithium-ion
icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
```

History (rate):
    1460455421    0.011    fully-charged

Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for Unix & Linux SE!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think a laptop external battery pack has any information other than whether the AC is connected/disconnected; the connector is not designed to carry digital information. If you have other information, e.g. remaining capacity, then it is probably an internal battery. This refers to a laptop, not a tablet or phone.